# Using HTTPS and multiple NSURLProtectionSpace's in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, https, nsurl

I'm creating a iOS app that requires the user to log in at startup, and then uses those credentials to query 4-5 different services on a server over the course of the session.

The server (xyz) it self doesn't accept the credentials, but if the services that it provides are queried then they get accepted. For example `https://xyz/service1` works, `https://xyz` doesn't.

Now what I'm wondering about is if there is anything that stands in the way of creating 4-5 `NSURLProtectionSpace`'s at log in, one for each service on the server, and then use the corresponding protection space when use each service?
Or is there a better way of implementing something that could work in this situation?

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there is nothing that stands in the way of creating multiple `NSURLProtectionSpace`'s since each is created for a separate url.